# How do I get the dropped on node of a uwp treeview?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

My TreeViewList control has the following event for _OnDragItemsCompleted

I want to know how to get the node that got dropped on.
Or am I using the wrong event?

```
  private void ListControl_OnDragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
  {

      var obj = args.Items.FirstOrDefault();  // just get the first for now
      var tvn = obj as TreeViewNode;
      var item = tvn.Content as StackPanel;
      var dep = item.DataContext as Department;

      if (args.DropResult == DataPackageOperation.Move)
      {
          // how do I get the dropped on?
      }

  }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemscompleted

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, drag and drop between tree views is preview. if you want get `DragItems` you could add  `DragItemsCompleted` event handler for [`TreeViewList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#pictures-and-music-library-tree-view) in the `ControlTemplate` of `TreeView`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}"
                                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                                  CanDragItems="True"
                                  AllowDrop="True"
                                  DragItemsCompleted="ListControl_DragItemsCompleted"
                                  CanReorderItems="True">
                        <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <ContentThemeTransition />
                                <ReorderThemeTransition />
                                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    </TreeViewList>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void ListControl_DragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var item in args.Items)
    {
        var tem = item as TreeViewNode;
        var parent = tem.Parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: how does this get the dropped on node?

Comment: Do you means you want get the  parent node that contain the placed node?

Comment: yes please. However maybe  the answer is that I don't need to because binding magic does everything.  I am thinking of my old vb6 days.

Comment: You could get the parent with `TreeViewNode`  `Parent` property, I have update the code please check.

Comment: I think he wants whatever the item was under when the user dropped?  In that case, you'd want to monitor the dragover events of the items to keep track of what the user was last over.

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT Monitoring DragOver event in UWP TreeView but it does not fire up. Had extended TreeView control and added delegate for DragOver event but it does not fire? (alos DragEnter and DragLeave does not fire)

Comment: @VladacusB you need to listen to DragOver on the TreeViewItems not the TreeView itself.

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT How can I reference TreeViewItems from inside or outside of TreeView?

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT And how to do this in MVVM way?

Comment: I would hook each TreeViewItem's drag/drop event up to a central handler in the View, and then fire whatever command in your ViewModel when the item is dropped with the proper parameters with the item dropped and what it was dropped on.